# Is there a way to make my dashboard accessible exclusively by its 'Slug'?

Tags: apache-superset

I have a public dashboard with a slug 'test', that i can access using

```
{baseURL}/superset/dashboard/test
```

The problem is that I can also access it by using its id

```
{baseURL}/superset/dashboard/id
```

Since the dashboard's id is incremental and my dashboards need to be public, client X may find client Y dashboard simply by incrementing the id on the url.

Is there any way to disable access by id ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about this, you can define separate roles on the basis of your clients and assign those roles to your dashboards accordingly. So, users will only be able to access those dashboards if they are allowed to.